# Insert into table with select statement plus additional column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert into a table from a select statement as well as add additional parameters to the rows with something like-

```
SELECT 
        Appt_ID,
        Pracitioner_ID,
        Appt_Book_ID,
        Start_Time,
        UR_NO,
        [Type],
       [Description]
FROM @TempWaiting,
 @EndTime,
 @PatientID, 
 @Title, 
 @FirstName, 
 @LastName, 
 @Surname, 
 @DOB
INTO PS_WAITING_LIST(Appt_ID,   
        Pracitioner_ID,
        Appt_Book_ID,
        Start_Time,
        UR_NO,
        [Type],
        [Description],
        End_Time,
        Patient_ID, 
        Title,
        First_Name,
        Middle_Name,
        Surname,
        DOB)
```

This is within a stored procedure and all it says is error after INTO.

I also tried re-writing it as -

```
insert into PS_WAITING_LIST (
        Appt_ID,    
        Pracitioner_ID,
        Appt_Book_ID,
        Start_Time,
        UR_NO,
        [Type],
        [Description],
        End_Time,
        Patient_ID, 
        Title,
        First_Name,
        Middle_Name,
        Surname,
        DOB)
SELECT 
        Appt_ID,
        Pracitioner_ID,
        Appt_Book_ID,
        Start_Time,
        UR_NO,
        [Type],
        [Description]
FROM @TempWaiting,
 @EndTime,
 @PatientID, 
 @Title, 
 @FirstName, 
 @LastName, 
 @Surname, 
 @DOB
```

This throws an error saying the number of select value must match the number of insert column. Well obviously that does not.

I also tried Insert into table (col1, col2..) Select * from (select (...), col3, col9)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Generally it works like this

```
insert into your_table (col1, col2, col3)
select some_column, @aVariable, 'static_string'
from another_table
```

Comment: even if @aVariable does not belong to another_table?

Comment: variables never belong to a table.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a table with many columns listing them all out can be tedious. To add a column to the end of the insert, for instance, a loggedAT or recreatedAt timestamp the following can be done. First create a dts column as the last column, then

```
INSERT INTO users_log SELECT *, NOW() FROM users WHERE id=?;
```

In this instance, we now know when the column has been added to our users_log table. The final case would be we may also want a primary key that is specific to the users_log table. lets modify the users_log table once more by adding a 'key' column to the end of the table setting it to be PK, AUTO, UNSIGNED. We can now populate that id with:

```
INSERT INTO users_log SELECT *, NOW(), '' FROM users WHERE id=?;
```

Now we have an exact copy of the user record including the PK from the user table and in our users_log table we can now track when the record was copied over and produce its own PK. Note that the users_log table would need to be modified to remove the PK from id that would have been from the users table to prevent id conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that @tempWaiting is a variable table the statement should be like this.

```
    insert into PS_WAITING_LIST (
    Appt_ID,    
    Pracitioner_ID,
    Appt_Book_ID,
    Start_Time,
    UR_NO,
    [Type],
    [Description],
    End_Time,
    Patient_ID, 
    Title,
    First_Name,
    Middle_Name,
    Surname,
    DOB)
SELECT 
    Appt_ID,
    Pracitioner_ID,
    Appt_Book_ID,
    Start_Time,
    UR_NO,
    [Type],
    [Description],
    @EndTime,
    @PatientID, 
    @Title, 
    @FirstName, 
    @LastName, 
    @Surname, 
    @DOB
FROM @TempWaiting
```

Comment: yes works. +1 but juergen pointed out first. So I will accept his.

Comment: No problem I just try to help out :D

Answer (score 0):

You may also try the following:

```sql
Insert Into CustomerNew (CustomerId, CustomerName) 
  SELECT CustID, Name
  FROM CustomerOld WHERE CustomerId Is not Null
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two tables, table **first** and **second**

- The first table contains products and prices
- The second table has column month and column total

I wanted to update the second table with the sum of products in the first table plus month.

I found this query useful I think you might play around to solve your problem

```
INSERT INTO second (month, total) SELECT 'JANUARY' SUM(PRICE) AS TOTAL FROM first
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case the **id** field in both tables was auto-incrementing so when I merged the tables, one inside the other, it threw an error because some id's matched.

to correct this you have to call the '**nextval**' function (I'm using postgres). The complete syntax would be:

`insert into your_table select nextval('your_table_id_seq') AS id, column_1, column_2, column_3, 'static_string' AS column_name from another_table.`